# Excel- combining multiple CSVs into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Excel 2016 on Windows 10:
I have 120 CSV documents each containing 10 columns of text data (A-J). None of the CSVs have any column headings- Row 1 contains the first row of data rather than headings.

I want to merge all 120 CSVs into one CSV, whilst only keeping columns A, C and D. I don't care about columns, B and E-J. These don't need to be in the final CSV (however I can always delete those columns from the final CSV afterwards...).
Column A contains post codes, C contains X coordinates and D contains Y coordinates (all unique).

How can I merge these 120 CSVs together in the way I want? Thanks

Comment: A plugin may help, so a search similar to `combine multiple columns from different workbooks` [(search)](https://www.google.com/search?q=merge+columns+from+multiple+work+books&oq=merge+columns+from+multiple+work+books&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9567j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) brings up https://www.extendoffice.com/

Answer (score 1):

OK so with all the CSVs in one folder, I used command prompt to combine them into one CSV.
[directory of csv files]>copy *.csv combine.csv

produces a CSV called 'combine.csv'

I then manually deleted the columns I didn't need.

Comment: Note that from within the directory with the files, you can open a command prompt with `shift+right-click`, and pick PowerShell from the options. For some reason the command doesn't work directly in PowerShell, but you can type `cmd` to open a command prompt within PowerShell, and then it will work.